spring boot realtime notification with WebSocket
I have this ecommerce project that I am working on using spring boot. I want to implement a notification to it. What I am  trying to achieve is that when a buyer place an order, I want to send a notification to the owner(s) of that product that an order has been placed for delivery as well as also sending a notification to the buyer that he/she has placed an order successfully along with the content of the order. Note that I want the content of the notification to include the order that was placed and I also want the notification to be sent to all the owners of the products that was purchased. What I mean is that a buyer might decide to select a product from different product's owners, add them together in his/her cart before checking out. In my product implementation, each product has an owner id attached to it so I want to send the notification to all the owners that's associated to the product(s) that was added to the cart as well as their product details. I thought of using WebSocket for this but I don't really know how to implement it. I will be glad if someone can give me a guide on how to achieve that or if there is any other way that I can achieve that easily apart from using WebSocket.

Websocket should be fine. I recommend reading https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/server.html - it describes quite well how to implement websocket in your application. Additionally, a tip from me, typically with logic like yours, in order to send some message to the appropriate users, you should save all active sessions along with your user IDs in some map implementation for easy choose with user should get message.

Ooh, please do you have a sort of code sample to showcase that as I don't really know how the implementation should be done @cichyvx?

https://github.com/emalock3/spring-boot-websocket-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/emalock3/websocket/EchoWebSocketHandler.java that's the part of sessions stored in map. Also look at Application class, with that sort of implementatnion you must do endpoint mappings by yourself. After that you can connect to your application by ws://localhost:{your_port}/echo
